# Installing Maven 3.1.1 on Maverick and working with eclipse-Kepler TLM terminal plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, osx-mavericks

I recently installed OS X 10.9 Mavericks. As it does not come with Maven pre installed, I installed Maven 3.1.1 manually. I exported maven and set its path in .bash_profile. It is accessible from command line. But it is not accessible from within eclipse TLM terminal plugin or Wicked Shell plugin.

One workaround I got is, I added same export statement in .bashrc and it is accessible now from within eclipse aforementioned terminal plugins. Is there any better solution for it? Can anybody explain how many .bash* files are there in mac and when each one is initialised ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have eclipse pick up the new addition to your PATH, you need to edit `/etc/launchd.conf` to set the environment variable explicitly.  Environment variable substitutions such as $PATH will not work.  To correct do an `echo $PATH` in terminal and copy what it returns.  Then, add this line to the launchd.conf file and restart your machine.

```
setenv PATH <your echo $PATH results here>
```

After, all should return to normal in eclipse.  Hope this helps!